# Can I toggle the Helm On/Off in Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm just wondering is it possible to toggle my helmet on/off but still have the same stats present like in World of Warcraft for a wholesome decorative look?

Comment: [related comic illustration](http://depressedalien.com/171.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can indeed, it is under the Gameplay options as seen in this image here: [image: screen shot of options for helm display]

Comment: Cheers! See you in-game :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember correct menu but - yes you can. Setting > Graphic or Settings > Gameplay. "Show Helmet" or something.

Good games